# Regex Replacing only whole matches

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace a bunch of strings in files. The strings are stored in a datatable along with the new string value.

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
foreach (DataRow dr in FolderRenames.Rows)
{
    contents = Regex.Replace(contents, dr["find"].ToString(), dr["replace"].ToString());

    File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);

    File.WriteAllText(file, contents);
}
```

The strings look like this `_-uUa`, `-_uU`, `_-Ha` etc.

The problem that I am having is when for example this string "`_uU`" will also overwrite "`_-uUa`" so the replacement would look like "newvaluea"

Is there a way to tell regex to look at the next character after the found string and make sure it is not an alphanumeric character?

I hope it is clear what I am trying to do here.
Here is some sample data:

```
private function _-0iX(arg1:flash.events.Event):void
    {
        if (arg1.type == flash.events.Event.RESIZE) 
        {
            if (this._-2GU) 
            {
                this._-yu(this._-2GU);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

The next characters could be `;`, `(`, `)`, dot, comma,  space, `:`,  etc.

Comment: How does a "find" string *end* in relationship to the "contents"? (It is usually good to show sample data with edge/expected cases.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `Regex.Escape`.

You can use then

```
contents = Regex.Replace(
  contents, 
  Regex.Escape(dr["find"].ToString()) + @"(?![a-zA-Z])",
  Regex.Escape(dr["replace"].ToString()));
```

or even better

```
contents = Regex.Replace(
  contents, 
  @"\b" + Regex.Escape(dr["find"].ToString()) + @"\b",
  Regex.Escape(dr["replace"].ToString()));
```

Comment: contents = Regex.Replace(
  contents, 
  Regex.Escape(dr["find"].ToString()) + @"(?![a-zA-Z])",
  Regex.Escape(dr["replace"].ToString()));   This would remove the next character if it  is alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
contents = Regex.Replace(
    contents,
    string.Format(@"(?<!\w){0}(?!\w)", Regex.Escape(dr["find"].ToString())),
    dr["replace"].ToString().Replace("$", "$$")
);
```

You can't use `\b` because your search strings don't always start and end with word characters.  Instead, I used `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` to make sure the matched substring is not immediately preceded or followed by a word character (i.e., a letter, a digit, or an underscore).  I don't know the complete specs for your search strings, so this pattern might need some tweaking.

None of the sample patterns you provided contain regex metacharacters, but like the other responders, I used `Regex.Escape()` to render it safe anyway.  In the replacement string the only character you have to watch out for is the dollar sign ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx)), and the way to escape that is with another dollar sign.  Notice that I used `String.Replace()` for that instead of `Regex.Replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two tricks that can help you here:

1. Order all the search string by length, and replace the longest ones first, that way you won't accidentally replace the shorter ones.
2. Use a MatchEvaluator and instead of looping through all your rows, search fro all replacement patterns in the string and look them up in your dataset.

Option one is simple, option two would look like this:

```
Regex.Replace(contents", "_-\\w+", ReplaceIdentifier)

public string ReplaceIdentifier(Match m)
{
   DataRow row = FolderRenames.Rows.FindRow("find"); // Requires a primary key on "find"
   if (row != null) return row["replace"];
   else return m.Value;
}
```